# php editor/compiler/whatever that shows errors in my code

Tags: php, editor

Lets say I have some code:

```
  <?php
  echo "Hello Everybody!";
  echo "<br/>" ;
  $var1 = 23 ;  
  var_dump($var1)   ;

  $str = <<<HERE

  some random text
  more random strings

  HERE;

  echo $str ;
?>
```

Now running this as index.php on localhost , gives a blank page. Thats probably because there is some error in the code. Now is there something(editor,compiler,whatever) that will tell me exactly where and what my error is ?

Currently I use one of those portable servers (XAMP , netserver,uniserver) to run my php pages, which works good , but it doesn't tell me what errors are there in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you should use for this is PHP.

Make sure [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is set to something high, such as [`E_STRICT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php):

> In PHP 5 a new error level `E_STRICT` is available. As `E_STRICT` is not included within `E_ALL` you have to explicitly enable this kind of error level. Enabling `E_STRICT` during development has some benefits. `STRICT` messages will help you to use the latest and greatest suggested method of coding, for example warn you about using deprecated functions.

Comment: THanks . i had no idea about this. will explore this option.

Comment: @user161179 - did you restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I'll let others to answer the question of the editor. I'll answer the error part in the code:

```
  HERE;
```

to

```
HERE;
```

There should be no leading space where the [**heredoc**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) ends. From the manual:

> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

Comment: thanks, that extra space was added by the editor I was using. BUT I am here to find a tool that would tell me about such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini to see if [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Many IDEs offer this functionality - NetBeans being one that comes to mind, Dreamweaver CS5 to a certain extent.

They will highlight blatant syntax errors like missing semicolons/unbalanced bracers.

But bear in mind if a compiler could identify every error then they could fix them too. no idea will help fix poor programming logic etc.

also as an answer below highlights, error_reporting can be turned off so should be turned on for development.

Answer (score 0):

Make new page, call it index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include('content.php');
```

content.php should be the page where your code is,

Now it will show your error!
Also i problem i noticed couple of days ago when you're working on a tmp-server.

Comment: indent your code-blocks by 4 spaces to get the goodness of syntax highlighting. Code blocks interpret newlines in your source as a new line in the output.

Comment: Done, 'text to fill commentbox'

Comment: The error shown with this method : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\UniServer\www\content.php on line 27 . not exactly accurate...

Comment: Don't forget to add the <?php open tag + ?> close tag.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you just want to do a quick syntax check, use the `-l` switch with the php binary.

`php -l myscript.php`